# No Bluetooth Found, Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, dongle

I've been using Bluetooth on this new Dell Laptop for about a year now... For several months with Ubuntu 20.04; and then Ubuntu 21.10 for the last 6 months... Until yesterday.  Today NO Bluetooth!   It's asking for a dongle!

I have made absolutely NO changes to the software or hardware!

I have tried many suggestions posted in Ask Ubuntu and other Ubuntu forums on the internet.

Would appreciate help from the Ubuntu community.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: Typically it would be helpful for us to know what specific error you are running into and providing as much information as possible. What model Dell? What information can you provide for the built-in Bluetooth adapter? Can you tell us what kernel you using? etc. The more information you provide us the better off we are at being able to help you. When you do provide more information, please update the question.

Comment: Open the Bluetooth settings panel, and assure that it's enabled via the slide switch at the top of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth problem solved.

When I loaded Ubuntu onto this new Dell laptop about 1 year ago, I partitioned the hard drive and installed Ubuntu, but kept Windows.

Upon checking few hours ago, I could not find the bluetooth device listed in the Windows Device Manager. It was hidden and inactive (discovered this after quite some effort...).

I noticed that about 8 drivers were not updated for a long time - because I mostly work in the Ubuntu O/S.  All drivers updated - and Bluetooth works in Ubuntu and Windows.

Cheers!